# SSIS configuration in sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml

Is it possible to store the connection string of the package and some variables in the sql server so package reads it from db rather than config xml file? If so how ?

thanks.

Comment: do you try to get the connection data for the database FROM the database to connect to?

Comment: well, i have got some variables that business wants to turn on/off controls based on the value. I was wandering if those variable could be stored in the db. yes also connection string? is it a good idea? i don't know i am trying to find.

Comment: well, the connection string would be kind of hard to achieve, since you need to be connected to the database to fetch data. And without connection-string its hard to connect to. You can surely store the other variables in a table/database, but somehow I feel that a plain xml-config file would serve the same purpos ( global table with unique entries/settings vs xml file containing the same )

Answer (score 0):

This may work - based on an SSIS design of execute a query to get a value using a database (con1), store the value in an SSIS variable, this variable is a connection string that is the expression of a different connection to a database (con2):

[This article addresses how you can execute a query and store the result in an SSIS variable](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-execute-sql-task-to-generate-result-sets/), similar to what you want (except in this case, the query will be to grab a connection string in a database).  This means that you'll want the expression of your connection strings to be variables that are entered through a query against some "control database" (based on the above comment).  Assuming there's a field next to the connection string that represents on/off (like 1 or 0), you can have the query that will pass the string include a where clause to control for this.

However, as user @Najzero mentions, if you are going to store these parameters in the database you want to connect to, you have a chicken and egg problem - you need be connected to the database in order to grab the connection credentials.  This means you must have a separate database for the initial connection (con1).